# Controlling the pursuit path of the human eye

Tags: vision, human-eye, iris

The human eye scans images by panning focus along a certain path. [Stork et al. (2002)](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0167945702001197) revealed that there is a feedback process involved in moving ocular focus along a path that produces minimum muscular stress.

This got me thinking that, possibly, I could augment a video such that I slightly blur most of the image in each frame leaving a path (with some significant width) of the unblurred image or a path of clarity, if you will, to "control" a third party's ocular pursuit path. I hypothesize that this control would be won from imposing a path of clarity , because the eye adjusts it's pursuit path to reduce stress.

Could you help me to decide if this is even remotely possible?

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. You said `I've read that [..]`. Can you please to link to your source as it could be helpful.

Comment: That comment pulls from a few places, but search this: "Intentionally-evoked modulations
of smooth pursuit eye movements".  It might help.

Comment: Assuming the the article for which you give the title reported the claim you're doing, I edited the post to include this reference. Thanks +1